# Unable to instantiate activity from library

Tags: android

I am trying to create an application that has different flavours (e.g. free, paid), by putting as much common code as I can into a library, and making projects for each flavour. At the moment, the Java class for the main activity will be the same in all versions, it is merely the layout and some constants defined in the "values" resource directory that need to change to control the behaviour.

I have defined the activity in my "free" project's manifest file as follows:

```
<activity
        android:name="librarypackagename.Foo"
        android:label="@string/bar" 
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But when testing the application, I receive the following error:

"Unable to instantiate Activity ComponentInfo{freeapppackagename/librarypackagename.Foo}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "librarypackagename.Foo" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/freeapppackagename-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/freeapppackagename-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]"

Is it not possible to use an activity from a library as the main activity? I have also tried this by extending Foo in my free app project, and using that as the main activity, but I still get the same exception.

Edit (removed manifest files, as it turned out they weren't related to the issue):

Also, in Eclipse, I've just noticed I am getting the following error message (although the project still builds):

> Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
>    but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
>    All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
>    Versions found are:
>    Path: D:\Work\Eclipse\LiteApplicationName\libs\android-support-v4.jar
>       Length: 556198
>       SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
>    Path: D:\Work\Eclipse\LibraryName\libs\android-support-v4.jar
>       Length: 385685
>       SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
>    Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Strangely enough, the android-support-v4.jar file appears in "Referenced Libraries" in the application project, but in "Android Private Libraries" in the library.

Comment: please check your package.

Comment: I've used a library activity as a main activity, so it's certainly possible. Perhaps if you post the entire manifest for both the free project and the library project we can see something.

Comment: I've updated the question with the two manifest files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was related to the library mismatch issue. I right clicked on the application project, and selected Android Tools > Add Support Library. This installed a package, and then "android-support-v4.jar" appeared in the application project's "Android Private Libraries" directory as well. Now I am no longer getting the exception.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things to look out for.

- Where you define your activity's class, ensure you have something to the effect of `package com.librarypackagename;` at the top of the file.
- You should have two AndroidManifest.xml files, one for your library and one for your main project.
- In your library AndroidManifest.xml, ensure that the element defining your activity has a parent XML tag that is `<library>` and not `<application>`
- In your library AndroidManifest.xml, ensure that you are setting the package attribute to something like `com.librarypackagename`

Let me know if you have any questions about any of these points. It would be helpful if you provided more information about the current structure of your project.

Comment: There is no `<library>` element that goes in an [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) file. There's a `<uses-library>`, but that's for an application that uses code from another package separately installed on the system.

Comment: Oddly enough I get `library` as an autocomplete candidate when writing my manifest in Android Studio, but yeah, that might not be used for anything. Feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Tried changing "application" to "library" in the library's manifest, to no effect.